# GMP on visual studio c++

Tags: visual-studio, gmp

I'm new for the c++ programming. I installed OpenSSL for my visual studio. I would like to install GMP for visual studio. How should I do that? There is no file such as gmp.exe. I dont know how to install this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please put a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73852387/941531), just  wrote it now, it describes in very details 3 ways of compiling GMP and MPIR under Windows VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't that hard to install GMP on windows.

First, download the GMP tar file. You have to install cygwin on windows with gcc, make and m4. 
You can then run linux command using cygwin. Decompress the tar file, then (RECOMMEND to check out the INSTALL file).

Do `./configure`, if you need anything special like running c++ gmp code, you have to add flags. 
Do`./configure --help` to check it out. 
Then run `make`, `make check`, and finally run `make install`.

You will have to add the path back to your project properties. Enjoy !